# Group and count by time interval - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data looks like this

```
name     first_appear      last_appear
Bob      12:10:00          12:33:49
Jacob    12:31:00          13:29:12
```

How can I group it by time range and count like this

```
  Interval        Count
10:00 - 11:00       0
11:00 - 12:00       0
12:00 - 13:00       2
13:00 - 14:00       1
14:00 - 15:00       0
```

**Explanation:**

Bob appeared from `12:10` to `12:33` so add 1 to count `12:00 - 13:00`

Jacob appeared from `12:31` to `13:29` so add 1 to count `12:00 - 13:00` and to count `13:00 - 14:00`

---

I'm using Python 3.9, the input is a Pandas dataframe, but can be restructured if needed
`first_appear` and `last_appear` are `datetime.time` objects

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I may have a solution for you, it's a little brute force, since I don't know the constraints of your question nor do I have a minimally reproducible example, I used a nested for loop (I know), but it may be possible to use a pandas dataframe.apply method here. Anyways:

Your Frames:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, time

Data = pd.DataFrame(
{
 "name":["Bob", "Jacob"],
 "first_appear":[datetime.strptime("12:10:00", '%H:%M:%S').time(), datetime.strptime('12:31:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()],
 "last_appear":[datetime.strptime('12:33:49', '%H:%M:%S').time(), datetime.strptime('13:29:12', '%H:%M:%S').time()]
 }
)

#Assuming you want the names as the index, and not as a column 
Data = Data.set_index("name", drop=True)

IntFrame = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Interval":[time(i) for i in range(10, 16)],
     "Count":0}
    )
```

And the nested loop:

```
for index1, index2 in zip(IntFrame.index.values[:-1], IntFrame.index.values[1:]):
for i in Data.index.values:
    First = Data.loc[i, "first_appear"]
    Last = Data.loc[i, "last_appear"]
    if (First >= IntFrame.loc[index1, "Interval"] and First < IntFrame.loc[index2, "Interval"]):
        IntFrame.loc[index1, "Count"] += 1
        if Last >= IntFrame.loc[index2, "Interval"]:
            #gets the last position where 'Last' is greater than a time interval
            Index3 = max(IntFrame.where(Last >= IntFrame["Interval"]).dropna().index.values)
            IntFrame.loc[index2:Index3, "Count"] += 1
```

Which produces:

```
   Interval  Count
0  10:00:00      0
1  11:00:00      0
2  12:00:00      2
3  13:00:00      1
4  14:00:00      0
5  15:00:00      0
```

I urge you not to treat your intervals like a 2-tuple, since its implied on a time scale. It's bad form to do that when working with data frames.

Comment: Perhaps would be good to add the imports?  Particularly, looks like the code is assuming `from datetime import time`  (that import is the most cryptic in being absent I think)

Comment: @skumhest Oops, added it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that whenever you work with `pandas` that you use their date/time objects, i.e. `Timestamp` and `Timedelta`.  Vectorised calculations will be much faster with these, as opposed to those from the `datetime` module, and it opens the door for a whole lot of extra functionality.

If you are willing to work with Timedelta (or Timestamp would work too) then you can use this solution using [`staircase`](https://staircase.dev), which is designed to be a part of the pandas ecosystem for handling step functions.

**setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time
```

data in `datetime.time` format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":["Bob", "Jacob"],
    "first_appear":[time.fromisoformat("12:10:00"), time.fromisoformat('12:31:00')],
    "last_appear":[time.fromisoformat('12:33:49'), time.fromisoformat('13:29:12')],
})
```

Convert to `pandas.Timedelta`

```
df["first_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["first_appear"].map(str))
df["last_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["last_appear"].map(str))
```

**solution**

Your data is essentially a step function of the count value.  When someone first appears the step function increases in value.  When they last appear the step function decreases in value.

We'll round the "first_appear" times down to the start of the hour, so that the value of the step function at each hourly point will give us the total number of people who were active at any point in that hour:

```
df["first_appear"] = df["first_appear"].dt.floor("H")
```

We can then create a step function using the `staircase.Stairs` object, passing it a dataframe and telling it which are the start times and end times

```
import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="first_appear", end="last_appear")
```

If you were using `pandas.Timestamp` you could plot the step function with `sf.plot()` but this functionality is not available with `pandas.Timedelta`.

Next, create your hourly sample times:

```
sample_times = pd.timedelta_range("10:00:00", "15:00:00", freq=pd.Timedelta("1hr"))
```

Lastly, you query the value of the Stairs (step function) object by calling it like a method with the times you want to evaluate it at:

```
sf(sample_times, include_index=True)
```

This will give you a `pandas.Series` indexed by `pandas.Timedelta`s:

```
0 days 10:00:00    0
0 days 11:00:00    0
0 days 12:00:00    2
0 days 13:00:00    1
0 days 14:00:00    0
0 days 15:00:00    0
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

note: I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: It's my first time using pandas and I'm amazed with the things you can do with it, I can confirm that this does exactly what I need as well

Comment: @Riley this is just amazing. I am facing a similar issues. Would you be kind enough to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586440/python-grouping-and-counting-time-intervals-by-hours-with-a-marker-for-overlap