# Grouping and counting time intervals by hours with a marker for overlapping days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I need to count the number of hour intervals over a monthly period. I  need to group it by only time and not by date. For example

| Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-02-2023 | 12:10:00 | 12:34:00 |
| 24-02-2023 | 12:15:00 | 12:45:00 |

would count 2 for 12:00:00 to 12:59:59 slot

My sample data looks like this (If needed I can change my sample data format)

| first_appear | last_appear |
| --- | --- |
| 12:10:00 | 12:31:00 |
| 12:33:49 | 13:29:12 |
| 15:30:20 | 18:40:30 |
| 20:12:20 | 23:10:20 |
| 23:34:20 | 6:11:00 |

If you notice the last entry denotes the overlap with the next day.
The code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import staircase as sc

df = pd.read_csv('Overlapping Schedule - Sheet2.csv')
df["first_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["first_appear"].map(str))
df["last_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["last_appear"].map(str))

df["first_appear"] = df["first_appear"].dt.floor("H")
df["last_appear"] = df["last_appear"].dt.ceil("H")

sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="first_appear", end="last_appear")

sample_times = pd.timedelta_range("00:00:00", "24:00:00", freq=pd.Timedelta("1hr"))
sf(sample_times, include_index=True)
```

The output

| 0 days 00:00:00 | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 days 01:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 02:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 03:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 04:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 05:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 06:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 07:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 09:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 10:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 11:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 0 days 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 14:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 16:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 17:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 18:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 19:00:00 | 0 |
| 0 days 20:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 21:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 22:00:00 | 1 |
| 0 days 23:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 days 00:00:00 | 0 |

Ideally I would like to see following entries as well

| 1 days 01:00:00 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 days 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 days 03:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 days 04:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 days 05:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 days 06:00:00 | 1 |

I referred to multiple Stack Overflow answers to come up with this but now I am stuck. @riley's answer to [Group and count by time interval - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214050/group-and-count-by-time-interval-python) helped me to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def get_hours(row):
    out = []

    if row["last_appear"] < row["first_appear"]:
        out.extend(
            pd.timedelta_range(
                row["first_appear"].floor("1h"),
                "24:00:00",
                freq="1H",
            )
        )
        out.extend(
            pd.timedelta_range(
                "00:00:00",
                row["last_appear"].floor("1h"),
                freq="1H",
            )
            + pd.Timedelta("1 day")
        )
    else:
        out.extend(
            pd.timedelta_range(
                row["first_appear"].floor("1h"),
                row["last_appear"].floor("1h"),
                freq="1H",
            )
        )

    return out


df["first_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["first_appear"])
df["last_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["last_appear"])

df = (
    df.assign(hours=df.apply(get_hours, axis=1))
    .explode("hours")
    .groupby("hours")["hours"]
    .count()
)
df = df.reindex(pd.timedelta_range("00:00:00", df.index.max(), freq="1H"), fill_value=0)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
0 days 00:00:00    0
0 days 01:00:00    0
0 days 02:00:00    0
0 days 03:00:00    0
0 days 04:00:00    0
0 days 05:00:00    0
0 days 06:00:00    0
0 days 07:00:00    0
0 days 08:00:00    0
0 days 09:00:00    0
0 days 10:00:00    0
0 days 11:00:00    0
0 days 12:00:00    2
0 days 13:00:00    1
0 days 14:00:00    0
0 days 15:00:00    1
0 days 16:00:00    1
0 days 17:00:00    1
0 days 18:00:00    1
0 days 19:00:00    0
0 days 20:00:00    1
0 days 21:00:00    1
0 days 22:00:00    1
0 days 23:00:00    2
1 days 00:00:00    2
1 days 01:00:00    1
1 days 02:00:00    1
1 days 03:00:00    1
1 days 04:00:00    1
1 days 05:00:00    1
1 days 06:00:00    1
Freq: H, Name: hours, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of minor adjustments to your code is all you need

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import staircase as sc

df = pd.read_csv('Overlapping Schedule - Sheet2.csv')
df["first_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["first_appear"].map(str))
df["last_appear"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["last_appear"].map(str))

df["first_appear"] = df["first_appear"].dt.floor("H")
df["last_appear"] = df["last_appear"].dt.ceil("H")

df["last_appear"] += df.eval("last_appear < first_appear")*pd.Timedelta("1day") # added

sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="first_appear", end="last_appear")

sample_times = pd.timedelta_range("00:00:00", "48:00:00", freq=pd.Timedelta("1hr"))  # extend to 48 hours
sf(sample_times, include_index=True)
```